# Should I use `this` or `$scope`?

Tags: angularjs

There are two patterns in use for accessing controller functions:  `this` and `$scope`.

Which should I use and when?  I understand `this` is set to the controller and `$scope` is an object in the scope chain for views. But with the new "Controller as Var" syntax, you can easily use either. So what I'm asking is what is best and what is the direction for the future?

Example:

1. Using `this`

   ```
   function UserCtrl() {
     this.bye = function() { alert('....'); };
   }
   ```

   ```
   <body ng-controller='UserCtrl as uCtrl'>
     <button ng-click='uCtrl.bye()'>bye</button>
   ```
2. Using `$scope`

   ```
   function UserCtrl($scope) {
       $scope.bye = function () { alert('....'); };
   }
   ```

   ```
   <body ng-controller='UserCtrl'>
       <button ng-click='bye()'>bye</button>
   ```

I personally find the `this.name` to be easier on the eye and more natural compared to other Javascript OO patterns.

Advice please?

Comment: Using 'this' seems to be new as of Google I/O 2013 http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HCR7i5F5L8c Also, check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Comment: Is the "UserCtrl as uCtrl" syntax new?  I don't see it documented on the 1.0.6 or 1.1.4 ngController pages.

Comment: Okay, it is documented on the [new 1.1.5 ngController page](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngController).

Comment: Best Explanations for $scope and this                                                                                http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/

Answer (score 231):

Both have their uses. **First, some history ...**

$scope is the "classic" technique while "controller as" is much more recent (as of version 1.2.0 officially though it did appear in unstable pre-releases prior to this).

Both work perfectly well and the only wrong answer is to mix them in the same app without an explicit reason. Frankly, mixing them will work, but it will just add to the confusion. So pick one and roll with it. The most important thing is to be consistent.

Which one? That depends on you. There are many more examples out there of $scope, but "controller as" is picking up steam as well. Is one better than the other? That's debatable. So how do you choose?

**Comfort**

I prefer the "controller as" because I like hiding the $scope and exposing the members from the controller to the view via an intermediary object. By setting this.*, I can expose just what I want to expose from the controller to the view. You can do that with $scope too, I just prefer to use standard JavaScript for this. In fact, I code it like this:

```
var vm = this;

vm.title = 'some title';
vm.saveData = function(){ ... } ;

return vm;
```

This feels cleaner to me and makes it easy to see what is being exposed to the view. Notice I name the variable that I return "vm" , which stands for viewmodel. That's just my convention.

With $scope I can do the same things, so I'm not adding or detracting with the technique.

```
$scope.title = 'some title';
$scope.saveData = function() { ... };
```

So its up to you there.

**Injection**

With $scope I do need to inject $scope into the controller. I don't have to do this with controller as, unless I need it for some other reason (like $broadcast or watches, though I try to avoid watches in the controller).

**UPDATE**
I wrote this post about the 2 choices: 
http://www.johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/

Comment: Personally I also follow your approach using vm. The only code smell I've picked up is when you need to specifically interact with $scope, e.g. subscribing or broadcasting events, accessing form validation variables inside your controller etc. This leads to a somewhat mixed environment where you still need to inject $scope even though you use the controller as feature.

Comment: Right. $scope is still used for in that case, but it is used more as a service. When we inject angular services ($scope, $q, etc) they provide some feature we need. $scope allows us to watch, apply, uses messages as well as data binding. And even when using controller as, $scope is still used, its just abstracted

Comment: Thanks John, that's what my conclusion was as well.

Comment: I think using $scope in Directives and having inheritance automatically in DOM-Tree are important points about $scope. Having that kind of inheritance is a good idea, I don't know. It is like a global object and can causes unexpected bugs. $scope should be better documented.

Comment: `var vm = this;` do you need to call it 'vm' in the view, too? 'controller as vm'. Do they have to be the same?

Comment: @Javid the `vm` in the controller and view do not have to be the same name. i just do that by convention because it is easier to be consistent, it is short to type, and vm conveys that it is the View's Model (aka ViewModel). You can of course deviate from this if something else interests you.

Comment: Thank you @John. I watch your courses on [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/). I learn alot from you.

Comment: @JohnPapa - Why don't the SideWaffle templates "return vm;" when using Controller As?

Comment: @Kevin Controllers effectively act as a Ctor and thus return "this" already.

Comment: @JohnPapa I see this answer is dated back 2013. I am on the stage of finalizing my new app where I never once used `controllerAs`. I have used $scope through the app and never did I have an issue with overlapping scope. Now that I see more and more people using (or suggesting) `this` over `scope`, I am in a dilemma if I should spend my time rewriting everything from `$scope` to `this` which brought me to your answer here. So, as of today considering the Angular future, would you still suggest `So pick one and roll with it. The most important thing is to be consistent.`?

Comment: If your app works I would be highly cautious on rewriting anything in it. It works, after all. So the risk in changing code in a production app has to be outweighed by the reward. ControllerAs will help you be in a better place to mentally prepare for Angular 2, but you would still need to change code to get there or use ngUpgrade. So no ... given what you have said, I would not change an existing working app. However, you could slowly start to do this as you make changes to your app, 1 V+C at a time.

Comment: @JohnPapa as jason328 stated "$scope is being removed in Angular 2.0". If it is true, then what I should instead of $scope in my controller which uses $broadcast and $on.

Comment: there are EventEmitter constructs you can use in ng2

Comment: @JohnPapa Why is it called vm? We also define the controller functions so it's not only the data model. I'm confused.

Comment: vm == ViewModel == View's Model

Comment: I'm having trouble with a similar implementation of your answer, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315538

Comment: Quote "controller and view do not have to be the same name. i just do that". So you write `ng-controller="controller as vm"`, as also used in your awesome code style guide (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md). Why? If you name all your controllers `vm` in the view, you might as well not use the controllerAs-Syntax at all

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that when using bootstrap tabs, you start to see a reason for using var vm = this over $scope. Tabs have their own scope and so you can't use $scope as you'd think you could but you can use vm everywhere. So it has real functional reasons over just convention I think.

Answer (score 69):

`$scope` is being removed in Angular 2.0. Thus, using `this` would be an approach others want to follow as the date of release of Angular 2.0 comes closer.

Answer (score 40):

My opinion is that 'this' in javascript has enough issues on it's own, and that adding another meaning / use for it not a good idea.

I'd use $scope, for clarity's sake.

**UPDATE**

There is now the 'controller as' syntax, discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/84selECbp1I).  I am not a fan, but now that it's a more 'official' AngularJS construct it deserves some attention.

Comment: I think we first need to understand the new "UserCtrl as uCtrl" syntax before we can say which we think is better.

Comment: Re 'UserCtrl as uCtrl', I agree, this needs to be understood.  I think it's a bad idea, for most of the same reasons as the arguments made here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/84selECbp1I

Comment: If you are familiar with [oop in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) it makes perfect sense.  A controller is a class, and angular uses the new operator each time a controller is created.  You are welcome to dislike it, but stating there are issues with using 'this' is misleading.  It is an acceptable use case for 'this'.

Comment: $scope adds nothing to the clarity. In fact it can be be very difficult to know what is going on in the view when using $scope and you have nested scopes. The controller as syntax along with using this adds much more clarity. In the view it is nice and clear which controller's scope a method or property originates from.

Comment: I'm having trouble with a similar implementation of your answer, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315538

Comment: I agree with @ddelrio1986. Just had an issue with bootstrap tabs and agular with using var vm = $scope. Tabs have their own scope and so you aren't able to use this as you'd expect but with var vm = this, things just work as expected.

Answer (score 11):

I think Controller As is better as it allows for more easily nesting scopes as described by Todd Motto here:

http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Also, it will insure that you always have at least one . in your binding expression which forces you to follow the [don't bind to primitives](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1267) recomendation.

Plus you can decouple from the scope which is going away in 2.0.

Answer (score 7):

The Angular documentation explicitly tells you that using `this` is recommended. That, in addition to the fact that `$scope` is being removed is enough reason for me to never use `$scope`.

Answer (score 4):

jason328's "$scope is being removed in Angular 2.0" sounds a good reason to me. And I found another reason to help me make the choice: `this` is more **readable** -- when I see `fooCtrl.bar` in HTML, I immediately know where to find the definition of `bar`.

Updates: not long after switching to `this` solution, I started to miss `$scope` way that needs less typing

Answer (score 3):

### I prefer a combination.

A simple console.log of $scope and 'this' after populating them with some mock data will show you that.

$scope allows access to under the covers parts of a controller, for example:

```
$$ChildScope: null;
$$childHead: null;
$$childTail: null;
$$listenerCount: Object;
$$listeners: Object;
$$nextSibling: Scope;
$$prevSibling: null;
$$watchers: null;
$$watcherCount: 0;
$id: 2;
$parent: Object;
foo: 'bar';
```

** Properties and methods with $$ are not recommended to mess around with by the Angular team, but the $ can be safe game for doing cool stuff with $parent and $id.

'this' gets straight to the point, attaching 2-way-bound data and functions. You'll only see what you attached:

```
foo: 'bar';
```

### So why do I prefer a combination?

In ui-router nested apps, I can access the main controller, set and call universal values and functions inside a child controller:

In the Main Controller:

```
// Main Controller
var mainCtrl = this;
mainCtrl.foo = 'Parent at the bar';
```

In the Child Controller:

```
// Child Controller
var mainCtrl = $scope.$parent.mainCtrl;
var childCtrl = this;

// update the parent from within the child
childCtrl.underageDrinking = function(){
    mainCtrl.foo = 'Child at the bar';
}

// And then attach the child back to a property on the parent controller!
mainCtrl.currentCtrl = childCtrl;
```

Now, you can access parent from within child and child from the parent!

Answer (score 1):

Both work, but if you apply things that are appropriate for the scope to $scope, and if you apply things that are appropriate for the controller to the controller, your code will be easy to maintain. To the people who say "Ugh just use scope forget this Controller as syntax"...It may work the same but I wonder how you'll be able to maintain a huge application without losing track of things.