# How to manually update AngularJS view using ControllerAs syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing a dashboard with sortable, dockable, floatable widgets. One of the controls I'm using generates the floating widgets as HTML at the bottom of the DOM, before the closing `body` tag. This effectively removes actions done in the window controls from the controller scope they are generated in.

I'm developing this dashboard controller using `controllerAs` syntax available, but I can't figure out how to effectively update the view with this syntax when an external component does an action that affects the data for the view?

Note: This is not the only I'm facing that forces me to manually update the main view. There are also directives elsewhere on the page that perform actions that impact the view.

Ideally, I would never have to update the view manually, because I would be using all commands that happen within the built in Angular commands affecting digest loop - but this was not an option for me.

So... if I was using `$scope` I would be able to simply do:

```
$scope.$digest
```

Or

```
$scope.$apply
```

But how do I achieve the same affect using controller as?

```
var vm = this;
vm.array = [item, item];
vm.something = something;

//External something changes something on a vm.variable

vm.update! //How??
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With 'as' you are defining the way you will refer to your controller scope in you view.

So this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Is equal to this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <p>Hello {{main.name}}!</p>
</body>
```

Your controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.name = 'World';
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/q78C3QLOi394OnYNzyhJ?p=preview)

So basically you should be able to call `this.$digest` or `this.$apply` as you would do on `$scope`.

**UPDATE**

After doing some search, I think the correct solution should be using `$scope.apply()` or `$scope.digest()`.

Main resource:
[AngularJS’s Controller As and the vm Variable](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) 
There is [a comment](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/#comment-1577221361) rising your same question and the author replay:

> You can use $scope.$apply() in that case and just inject $scope for
>   that purpose (still using vm for everything else). However, if you
>   switch fro using ajax to using Angular's $http, then you won't need to
>   call $apply as angular's $http does that for you. That's what I
>   recommend

Other resources I found:

- [this vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)
- [Angular: Should I use this or $scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619740/angular-should-i-use-this-or-scope)
- [Do You Like Your Angular Controllers with or without Sugar?](http://www.johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/)

Comment: Using `var vm = this;` and then `vm.$digest();` causes an error: `Object doesn't support property or method '$digest'`.

Comment: I think you need to use `$scope.$digest()` or `$scope.$apply()` in this case. Have a look at [this article](http://www.johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/) where it explains about `$scope` injection

Comment: I've read that article before and I think it specifically mentions $scope injection in reference to watches or broadcasts, which makes me think there may be a way to apply updates without scope. There <i>should</i> be anyway.

Comment: `this` is not equal to `$scope`, so I still think that the right solution is `$scope.$apply()`, but since I am not 100% sure, I'll wait for other replies. I also add a couple of link to my answer to help investigate.

Comment: When using controllerAs, you must inject the `$scope` itself to the controller function. Then you can use normally `$scope.$apply()` etc

Answer (score 0):

Try to do your update in $scope.$apply block like this:

```
$scope.apply(function() {
    vm.something = some_new_value;
});
```

To avoid "Digest already in progress" error, wrap that in `$timeout`