# Is it possible to autoscroll in AngularUI Router without changing states?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularUI Router with Bootstrap. I have two views within the same state, and want to scroll to the second view when a button is clicked. I don't need to do any scrolling when the initial state and views load. I want the page to scroll to #start when the "Add More" button is clicked. I've attempted to use $anchorScroll to accomplish this, but am not having any luck.

Any suggestions on a good way to accomplish this?

HTML:

```
<!-- index.html -->

<div ui-view="list"></div>
<div ui-view="selectionlist"></div>

<!-- list.html -->

 <div id="scrollArea"><a ng-click="gotoBottom()" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" role="button">Add More</a>

<!-- selectionlist.html -->

<div class="row" id="start"></div>
```

Javascript for Controller:

```
myApp.controller('SelectionListCtrl', function (Selections, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    var selectionList = this;
    selectionList.selections = Selections;
    this.selectedServices = Selections;
    selectionList.gotoBottom = function() {

     $location.hash('start');
     $anchorScroll();
     };
  });
```

Javascript for Routes:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $uiViewScrollProvider) {
    $uiViewScrollProvider.useAnchorScroll();

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider

      .state('selection', {
              url: '/selection',
              views: {
                  'list': {
                      templateUrl: 'views/list.html',
                      controller: 'ProjectListCtrl as projectList'
                  },
                  'selectionlist': {
                      templateUrl: 'views/selectionlist.html',
                      controller: 'SelectionListCtrl as selectionList'

                  }
              }
              })
```

Comment: shouldn't it be 'a ng-click="gotoBottom()"' instead of 'a ng-click="gotoSection()"'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible to autoscroll in AngularUI Router without changing states.

---

As mentionned previously in my comment, you need to call the scrolling function with an `ng-click="gotoBottom()"` instead of an `ng-click="gotoSection()"`

Also, the function definition `gotoBottom()` must be in the `ProjectListCtrl`, not in the `SelectionListCtrl`. This is because the call `gotoBottom()` happens in the list view:

```
'list': {
templateUrl: 'list.html',
controller: 'ProjectListCtrl as projectList'
}
```

As `gotoBottom()` is called from the `list.html` view, the corresponding controller in `$stateProvider` must be the one where you define `gotoBottom()`.

**Here are two working ways of accomplishing your goal:**

---

**1**. You inject `$scope` inside the controller `ProjectListCtrl`. You then define the `$scope.gotoBottom` function in the same controller.

> The scope is the glue between the controller and the view. If you want to call a controller function from your view, you need to define the controller function with `$scope`

```
app.controller('ProjectListCtrl', function ($location, $anchorScroll,$scope) {
var selectionList = this;
//selectionList.selections = Selections;
//this.selectedServices = Selections;
$scope.gotoBottom = function() {
  console.log("go to bottom");
  $location.hash('start');
  $anchorScroll();
 };
});
```

In the `list.html` view, you can then call the `$scope.gotoBottom` function just with `gotoBottom()`: `ng-click="gotoBottom()"`

---

**2**. Or you use the ***controller as*** notation, as when you wrote `ProjectListCtrl as projectList`.

```
    this.gotoBottomWithoutScope = function(){
      $location.hash('start');
      $anchorScroll();
    };
```

With this notation, you write `this.gotoBottomWithoutScope` in the `ProjectListCtrl`. But in the view, you must refer to it as `projectList.gotoBottomWithoutScope()`.

Please find a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/diTpVzAIJAtXW7pR4GPF?p=preview)

---

To learn more about the `this` and `$scope` notations, please read this:

[Angular: Should I use this or $scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619740/angular-should-i-use-this-or-scope)

this: [AngularJS: "Controller as" or "$scope"?](http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/)

and this: [Digging into Angular’s “Controller as” syntax](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate the extra links and plunker as well. Thank you!