# How to inject variable into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I am trying to get started with angular.js but I can't figure out how to inject a simple variable into my controller before testing.

This is my controller:

```
angular.module("app").controller("SimpleController", SimpleController);

function SimpleController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.myVar = 1;
  vm.getMyVar = function() {
    return vm.myVar;
  };
}
```

My test looks like the following:

```
describe("SimpleController", function() {
  var vm;

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    vm = $controller('SimpleController', {
        $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
        myVar: 2
    });
  }));

  it('myVar should be 2 not 1', function() {
    expect(vm.getMyVar()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

I did a lot of google searching but this is really confusing because many people do use `$scope` in controller and not `this`as I do. But I guess the injection of variables should work with `this` too?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try writing your controller this way. This will make $scope accessible.

```
(function () {
   angular.module("app").controller("SimpleController", SimpleController);

   SimpleController.$inject = ['$scope'];
   function SimpleController($scope) {
      $scope.somevar = "something";
   }
})();
```

I'm sure you've probably came across the documentation, but here is a link to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) which contains the basics and should at least get you going in the right direction.

Another alternative would be something like this:

```
app.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.somevar = "something";
   ....
}]);
```

When you use $scope, you're making that property publicly available in the view.

Comment: Yes, I know the behaviour of `$scope`. In fact it seems like that you can use `$scope` and `this` in parallel (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619740/angular-should-i-use-this-or-scope). Lets say I use `$scope` and structure the controller as you suggested: How can I mock up somevar in my testcase to have another value?

Comment: @Jonny  var controller = $controller('SimpleController', { $scope: $scope }); $scope.myVar = 'something'