# Call function in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, function

I need help - how to call `myFunction` from AngularJS in area success?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("MyController", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.myFunction = function() {
    alert("HI");
  };

  $http.get('myWS.asmx/myService?callback=?', {
      params: {
        userName: 'test',
        procedureName: "EXECUTE myProcedure"
      }
    })
    .success(
      function(data) {
        //CALL MY FUNCTION HERE!
      })
    .error(
      function() {
        alert("ERROR");
      }
    );
});
```

I've tried several times but nothing; any solution or example?

Comment: Please edit and correct your question (repetitions), or I bet it will be closed pretty quickly. And give a bit of context, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `$scope.myFunction()` should work? Are you sure your `.get` even fires the `.success`?

Comment: @Goldenowner I get data in .success, $scope.myFunction() not working!

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: I've updated my answer, use .then instead of success and error

Answer (score 0):

```
 $http.get('myWS.asmx/myService?callback=?', {
    params: {
      userName: 'test',
      procedureName: "EXECUTE myProcedure"
    }
  })
  .success(
    function(data) {
      $scope.myFunction();
    })
  .error(
    function() {
      alert("ERROR");
    }
  );
```

basically.

Comment: @paris0000 This is correct.  If it's not working, then you're onto a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example,

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
            app.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {




                $scope.myFunction = function () {
                    alert("HI");
                };



        $scope.myFunctionLoadData = function () {
                    $http.get('myWS.asmx/myService?callback=?', {
                    params: {
                        userName: 'test',
                        procedureName: "EXECUTE myProcedure"
                    }
                })
                .success(
                    function (data) {
                        $scope.myFunction();
                    })
                .error(
                    function () {
                        alert("ERROR");
                    }
                );
                };


                $scope.myFunctionLoadData();


            });
```

Comment: As an aside, this will break if minified:  use the controller syntax...  app.controller("MyController", [ "$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) { ... } ]);

Comment: is the http request definitely succeeding?  (i.e. you can put an alert in the success function and it fires)

Comment: @Nathan Yes, I'm put alert!

Comment: I've created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8frmtwLr/3/ and the code above works... have you checked your console for other errors?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need $scope, just use *this*, and create an instance of *this* outside of the scope of your callback function:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("MyController", function($http) {

  var scope = this;

  this.myFunction = function() {
    alert("HI");
  };

  $http.get('myWS.asmx/myService?callback=?', {
      params: {
        userName: 'test',
        procedureName: "EXECUTE myProcedure"
      }
    })
    .then(
      function(data) {
        scope.myFunction();
      },
      function() {
        alert("ERROR");
      }
    );
});
```

Success and error don't work in the newer Angular versions, you want *.then*, with two functions inside.

Comment: now work function, but not working receive data from http!

Comment: Are you sure data is coming back?

Comment: Success and error work in my above example, only I don't how call any function. What do you want to update?

Comment: -1: not using $scope is very un-Angular and could lead to problems.  $scope is there for a reason, use it.  The other solution which defines the function on the scope and invokes it accordingly is the correct solution.

Comment: @Nathan John Papa suggests to use $scope as a service, but the controllerAs syntax when you don't need any of the functionality offered by $scope, as its one less dependency - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19940503/969613

Comment: @JMK given that you don't know the requirements or experience of paris0000, guiding him away from anything non-standard isn't helpful: all the AngularJS examples out there use scope, the answer you linked  will provide moderate benefits in exchange for (in this case, and in the case of most starters) additional confusion and/or potential for mistakes.  Keep it simple.

Comment: This is standard though, most modern examples of Angular will use controllerAs where as older examples tend to use $scope so I don't think it's wrong to introduce the syntax. Also using success and error, as in the other answer, is outdated and might not even work depending on the version of Angular used, .then is better.

Comment: @Nathan Relevant discussion on Reddit, the angular developers recommend avoiding $scope too - https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/20ztwx/5_guidelines_for_avoiding_scope_soup_in_angular/

Comment: Google's style guidelines also recommend avoiding $scope - https://google.github.io/styleguide/angularjs-google-style.html

Comment: @JMK I stand corrected, I've learned something new, thank you.  If you make a small edit to your answer, I'll be able to retract my -1.  Sorry.  :-)