# AngularJS: code not working when iterating through object

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I am trying to populate a list of `employee` objects from my controller `empctrl` in a template.

Here's the controller:

```
app.controller('employeeController', function ($scope, employeeService) {

    this.employees = {};

    this.populateTable = function (data) {

        this.employees = data;
    };

    var error = function (err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
    };

    // Call Service to List all Employees
    console.log("Service called to populate table.");
    employeeService.output().then(this.populateTable, error);
    this.populateTable();

});
```

However, this code that I wrote isn't working:

```
<div ng-repeat="employee in empctrl.employees.allEmployees" class="table_row">
    <div class="table_column" style="width:2%">{{ $index + 1 }}</div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width:8%">{{ employee.employeeName}}</div>
    <!-- 7 more columns -->
</div>
```

Nothing shows up in the UI.
Instead, if I write `$scope.employees` in the controller, it works:

```
<div ng-repeat="employee in employees.allEmployees" class="table_row">
```

Since I know how tempting it is to do `$scope.<everything>` in the controller, I'm trying to avoid using `$scope` as much as possible.

---

If someone could demonstrate the proper use of `$scope` and difference betwee `alias.abc` and `$scope.abc` (where `alias` is an alias of controller), I'll be thankful.

**Edit:** Exact same question is this: ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers/14168699#14168699)

Thanks for this link, PankajParkar.

Comment: Need to see more of your code (at least your controller code). Fiddle/plunker/codepen would be nice.

Comment: @LJ.Wizard What part of the code do you need? I'll add it.

Comment: Your controller code - `empctrl` by the looks of it. I assume you're using `controller as` syntax?

Comment: do you have use `ng-controller="employeeCtrl as empctrl"`(soemthing like this, assumed controller name as `employeeCtrl`)

Comment: @PankajParkar yes, I do.

Comment: Could you add your controller code, where you are getting employees?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `$scope`?

Comment: @Ties because of scope soup: http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html

Comment: @cst1992 I mark it as duplicate because the answer has efficient information about what you are asking..'

Comment: @PankajParkar Okay. I hope no one downvotes, though - it's hard to find one's exact question among the millions that are there.

Comment: @cst1992 frankly speaking [this is convenient one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19940503/2435473)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `this` which you are accessing inside `populateTable` function is not `this` which you have there in your controller function.

Better do keep `this` variable inside some variable, so that by having it you will make sure you are referring to correct object.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('employeeController', function ($scope, employeeService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.employees = {};

    vm.populateTable = function (data) {
        vm.employees = data;
    };

    var error = function (err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
    };

    // Call Service to List all Employees
    console.log("Service called to populate table.");
    employeeService.output().then(vm.populateTable, error);
    vm.populateTable();
});
```

For more detail, I'd highly recommend you to readup on [**this article**](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)

If you are confused with `this` vs `scope` then do read up on [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168699/2435473)

Comment: So if I use `var vm = this`, it'll work inside functions too?

Comment: @cst1992 yupe.. do try that..

Comment: If I use a `function()` syntax instead of `var x = function()` i.e. just write a declaration, will `this` still refer to the function rather than the controller?

Comment: Works, thanks. Could you help me with the alias vs scope thing? I want to know scenarios when $scope is the ideal solution. In this case it wasn't, but it must be in some other?

Comment: @cst1992 Ideally, if you ask me what to chose.. I'll recommend you to follow `this` instead of `scope`, as it will be best to access scope variable with aliases on view & will make you once step closer to angular2 migration.. Still if you want more detail you can refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14168699/2435473)

Comment: Excellent. Could you add this link in your answer?

Comment: @cst1992 done. Thanks :)

Comment: @cst1992, How a function is defined has no effect on what `this` refers to within the function.  The value of `this` is determined by how the function is called.  See [`this` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for details.

Comment: @kicken technically you can't extend this question. as referenced answer has efficient detail over it.. otherwise I'd mark it as duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

Add your variables to the `$scope` instead of `this` like:

```
$scope.customers = {};

$scope.populateTable = function (data) {
    $scope.employees = data;
};
```

**Edit:** both methods work. See [this article](http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/) for a in depth explanation.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Everything you bind to the `$scope` will be available in your view, which is what the `$scope` variable is designed to do.

Comment: @Ties this isn't correct answer..what OP wants to do is make working it with `controllerAs` approach.. which mean he have to have variable bounded to `this` context

Comment: Just trying to explain why this is also a good option. Because using `this` can be difficult sometimes with function contexts.

Comment: @Ties who said its difficult?

Comment: @PankajParkar because you have to assign `this` to a second variable to be able to use it inside functions

Answer (score 0):

Substituting **"this"** to vm (View-Model) will solve your issue. Not polluting $scope object is a groovy thing. **this** is a global context and its value depends on a function call.

So, in your controller just assign,

```
var vm = this;
  vm.empTable = function (data) {
  vm.employeeList = data.data; 
};
```

..and use the vm object elsewhere in your controller. It will be useful to keep the code clean while working with multiple controllers in a view.

Don't forget to give an alias name to the controller,

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <div ng-repeat=" employee in main.vm.employeeList ">
        {{employee.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the meaning of `vm`, I didn't know about that. BTW, using any name works fine; I'm using `Controller` in my own code to know that this variable has the controller's `this`.

Comment: Yes of course. Any name would be fine!