# Change a value inside ng-repeat cycle with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I want to change a value of an item inside an ng-repeat cycle using a function.

This for example won't work.

HTML

```
<ul class="unstyled">
  <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos">
      <span>{{todo.name}}</span>
      <button ng-click="example(todo)">Change me</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$scope.example = function(v) {
  v.name = 'i am different now';
};
```

Full example

http://plnkr.co/edit/kobMJCsj4bvk02sveGdG

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using `controllerAs` pattern, you should be using `controller` alias while accessing any variable from controller function. But that should be bounded to `this` context of `controller`.

```
<button ng-click="todoList.example(todo)">Click me</button>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/15Wmwl5Tlmvx67gUyd0X?p=preview)

**Extended**

Also keep in mind while using `this` keyword inside a controller factory function. You should assign `this` variable to some variable to ensure that `this` which you are using is not other `this`, look at [**`this` context related issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35647428/2435473).

```
angular.module('todoApp', [])
  .controller('TodoListController', function() {
    var toList = this;
    toList.todos = [{name:'test 1'},{name:'test 2'}];
    toList.example = function(v) {
      v.name = 'ora bene';
    };
  });
```