# Change a value inside ng-repeat cycle with a dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change a value of an item inside an ng-repeat cycle using a dialog and then a function.

This for example won't work.

HTML

```
  <div ng-controller="TodoListController as todoList">
    <ul class="unstyled">
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <span>{{todo.name}}</span>
          <button ng-click="todoList.example(todo)">Click me</button>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-if="todoList.show_box">
      <button ng-click="todoList.change_me()">Now change me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('todoApp', [])
  .controller('TodoListController', function() {
    this.todos = [{
      name: 'test 1'
    }, {
      name: 'test 2'
    }];

    this.example = function(v) {
      this.tmp = v;
      this.show_box = true;
    };

    this.change_me = function(v) {
       this.tmp.v.name = 'now it\'s ok';
    };
  });
```

Full example

http://plnkr.co/edit/kobMJCsj4bvk02sveGdG

Comment: I think i had already told you to keep `this` in some variable and then used it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35650598/2435473)

Answer (score 0):

Inside a function your `this` will point to something else, not your original controller `this`, you can solve it by doing the following.

```
var self = this;

self.todos = [{
  name: 'test 1'
}, {
  name: 'test 2'
}];

self.example = function(v) {
  self.tmp = v;
  self.show_box = true;
};

self.change_me = function(v) {
   self.tmp.v.name = 'now it\'s ok';
};
```

[more info about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('todoApp', [])
  .controller('TodoListController', function() {
    this.todos = [{
      name: 'test 1'
    }, {
      name: 'test 2'
    }];

    this.example = function(v) {
      this.tmp = v;
      this.show_box = true;
    };

    this.change_me = function(v) {
       this.tmp.name = 'now it\'s ok'; //this.tmp.v.name will give u undefined
    };
  });
```