# using angularjs $timeout with "this" insted of $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, this

i need to use angular $timeout to show element for 2 seconds. it works with $scope but i don't now how to use it with "this" keyword an "controller as ..." syntax.

https://plnkr.co/edit/GPWRg4acYVrP1Ry00D7z?p=preview

```
angular.module("test", [])
 .controller("testCtrl", function($scope, $timeout){

  $scope.boo = false;

  $scope.disappear = function(){
    $scope.boo = true;
    $timeout(function () {
     $scope.boo = false;
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do use `controllerAs` pattern while declaring controller over html like `ng-controller="testCtrl as vm"`. So that `vm` will have alias of controller basically which will be responsible `object` make values of `this` context over HTML for binding.

**Markup**

```
<body ng-controller="testCtrl as vm">
  <div>
    <button ng-click="vm.disappear()">button</button>
    <h1 ng-show="vm.boo">Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Code**

```
angular.module("test", [])
  .controller("testCtrl", function($timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.boo = false;

    vm.disappear = function() {
      vm.boo = true;
      $timeout(function() {
        vm.boo = false;
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/PDZznkHza7lbJJIYXbop?p=preview)

Additionally I'd also suggest you to place `this` context inside some variable so that you would not get issue related to this`. Refer [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35647428/2435473) for more information

Comment: thank you very much! you are right. i have tried it but without assigning this to variable and it did not worked. is this have something to do with javascript  local ang global scope?

Comment: @OleGunarSolskier yes..read up on reference answer which I've added there.. THank you.. :)