# Angular new object binding

Tags: angularjs

I have a page that supposed to create a new user object and post it to the server.

This is the html file:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="newUserCtrl">
...
 <tr>
     <td>Username:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="name" ng-value="user.username"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Password:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="name" ng-value="user.password"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Name:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="name" ng-value="user.name"></td>
 </tr>
...
</div>
```

This is the controller:

```
angular.module('module')
    .controller('newUserCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location',
          '$state', newUserCtrl]);


function newUserCtrl($scope, $http, $location,
                        $state) {

    $scope.user = {
      usrename: null,
      password: null,
      name: null
  };

  $scope.saveNewUser = function() {
    var aa = $scope.user;

    $http.post('SERVICE URL', $scope.user)
      .then(doSomething);
  }

}
```

The problem that the data is not binded to the $scope.user object. I insert stuff, then after invoking the save methond I can see that aa is the initail user object.

How can I do that?

Regards,
Ido

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker pls?

Comment: Btw, why do you use $scope? Why not to use ControllerAs syntax?

Comment: I am new to anguler and I am not familiar with ControllerAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ng-value` to `ng-model` to fix this.

**Here is a Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/R1kqBfzNHfkJK0fvKhgJ?p=preview**

**This solution is with $scope https://plnkr.co/edit/Cic7We?p=preview**

This approach is cleaner.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="newUserCtrl as nu">
...
 <tr>
     <td>Username:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="name" ng-model="nu.user.username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Password:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="name" ng-model="nu.user.password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Name:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="name" ng-model="nu.user.name"></td>
</tr>
...
</div>

angular.module('module')
    .controller('newUserCtrl', ['$http', '$location',
      '$state', newUserCtrl]);


function newUserCtrl($http, $location, $state) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.user = {
      usrename: null,
      password: null,
      name: null
   };

  vm.saveNewUser = function() {
    var aa = vm.user;

    $http.post('SERVICE URL', vm.user)
      .then(doSomething);
  }

}
```

Comment: No, changes nothing

Comment: @IdoBarash, I've added a Plunker. Check it pls.

Comment: Thanks,, you are great.

Just for my understanging:   why not use $scope?

Comment: To be short: there is a many ways to misuse $scope. And a good answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19940503/5453843 And you should definitely read this :) https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md