# Different Ways of attaching data to $scope in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am beginner of Angular 1, I understood that $scope is glue between vew and modal.

Could anyone tell me the difference between these three ways of defining a controller.

1)

```
   (function(angular) {
      'use strict';
       var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
       myApp.controller('namesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
         $scope.customSpice = 'wasabi';

       }]);
    })(window.angular);
```

Is there any use of passing array with values ['$scope',function]. Is function alone is not sufficient?

2)

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

3)

```
  (function(angular) {
    'use strict';
     angular.module('invoice1', [])
     .controller('namesCtrl', function namesCtrl() {
        this.customSpice = 'wasabi';
      });
    })(window.angular);
```

How they bond data to $scope in 3rd example I found this example at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `['$scope', function($scope){}]` is called as `Inline Array Annotation`.
   Angular maps `$scope`(after minification say `a`) with `'$scope'`. Useful when you plan to `minify` your code.
2. `Implicit Annotation`. Be careful in case of `minification`.
3. `controllerAs`. When you are using `controllerAs` syntax, e.g. `"myCtrl as ct"` angular does `$scope.ct = this`. Here, also you are using `$scope` as  glue between view and modal.

Answer (score 2):

Case 3rd:

Controlled is used as "controller as" syntax. This is the latest practice of binding with the DOM. Here the $scope variable is use in the context of current controller inside HTML.

However to use it inside closures or other functions you need to make a copy of reference to this context

eg: var cs = this;

Case 1 and 2 are almost same except that $scope is passed as dependency in case 1.

Read more here for benefits of each [Angular: Should I use this or $scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619740/angular-should-i-use-this-or-scope)