# AngularJS: $scope vs this: what is the use of $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I found this in [AngularJS style guide](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide)

> Prefer using controller as syntax and capture this using a variable:

That means that I can assign all my functions and the model to the controller via this and access via the alias in the view. If I do so, I find that I really have no use for the `$scope` anymore. One exceptions is when I want to access something that's in the `$rootScope`.

So, having the quoted suggestion in mind, when should I use `$scope` at all if I'm not interested in accessing anything in the `$rootScope`?

That is, should I move everything to controller's `this`? If not, then what should stay in the `$scope`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: Should I use this or $scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619740/angular-should-i-use-this-or-scope)

Comment: Not really a duplicate because it is focused on the opposite topic, why `this` should be favoured.

Answer (score 7):

> when should I use $scope at all if I'm not interested in accessing anything in the $rootScope?

- `$scope` is not just for accessing to properties or functions in the `$rootScope`. *Example (not too often, by the way):* Suppose you need to update a DOM element not in the angular way, it means updating it through any external library which modifies the component value (visually), but the `ng-model` of the component doesn't get updated and you need it to! What to do? Simple: `$scope.$digest` (depending on what you do, there might be any other angular function required).

> should I move everything to controller's this?

- No, you don't! Actually it is not a good idea to do that. Why? When you move everything to the controller's *this*, you are providing access to that "everything" from the view, which is impractical, since you don't need in the view everything is declared in the controller. In the controller sometimes (most of the time) you have variables and functions used just as complementary to others functions and variables (kind of private stuff): that should be kept "private", inside the controller. See example below:

---

```
angular
  .module('myapp', [])
  .controller('foo', function() {

    var vm = this;
    // only this will be available in the view thanks to the controller as syntax
    vm.wizard = {
      userID: null,
      totalCartCount: 0
    }

    // stuff used only inside the controller
    vm.private = {
      subtotalByProducts: [],
      readyToCheckoout
    }

    // only "public" stuff is returned here
    return vm.wizard;

    // functions
  });
```

> If not, then what should stay in the $scope?

What you put in your `$scope` is completely up to you, as it is using the `controller as` syntax, but keep in mind that everything in the `$scope` is accessible in the view. The idea is to reduce the amount of variables *passed* to the view. This could not be noticeable in small webapp, but when the size of the app gets greater you can notice some changes (more time loading, etc).

This is a matter of perspective of each developer and how fond could be any of us of using best practices.

Comment: @Asiel Leal Celdeiro Thanks for editing your answer. I upvoted your answer (but it wasn't me who downvoted it initially :)).

Answer (score 2):

Use of `this` instead of `$scope` was not allowed until Angular 1.2 was released. `$scope` was the original and this came to essentially supersede it as more often than not they can be used interchangeably. They ARE technically different, though, and it seems you would base a decision to use one over the other on when the function was being called.

From ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers/14168699#14168699):

`this` -

When the controller constructor function is called, `this` is the controller.
When a function defined on a `$scope` object is called, `this` is the "scope in effect when the function was called". This may (or may not!) be the `$scope` that the function is defined on. So, inside the function, `this` and `$scope` may not be the same.

`$scope` -

Every controller has an associated $scope object.
A controller (constructor) function is responsible for setting model properties and functions/behavior on its associated `$scope`.

Only methods defined on this `$scope` object (and parent scope objects, if prototypical inheritance is in play) are accessible from the HTML/view. E.g., from `ng-click`, filters, etc.

Clicking the first link will show that `this` and `$scope` are the same, since "the scope in effect when the function was called" is the scope associated with the `ParentCtrl`.

Clicking the second link will reveal `this` and `$scope` are not the same, since "the scope in effect when the function was called" is the scope associated with the `ChildCtrl`. So here, this is set to `ChildCtrl`'s `$scope`. Inside the method, `$scope` is still the `ParentCtrl`'s `$scope`.

I try to not use this inside of a function defined on `$scope`, as it becomes confusing which `$scope` is being affected, especially considering that `ng-repeat`, `ng-include`, `ng-switch`, and directives can all create their own child scopes.

Answer (score 2):

`$scope` should be used for the things that cannot be done with `this` (which equals to controller instance and becomes a property on `$scope` when being used with controllerAs syntax). This includes [all scope methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new).

For some of these methods `$scope` can generally be replaced with `$rootScope`, but it is semantically correct to not do that (not doing that may also be good for testability). The examples are `$apply`/`$evalAsync` without string argument, `$on`/`$broadcast`/`$emit` for events which are used exclusively on root scope.

For some of these methods `$scope` cannot be replaced with `$rootScope`, doing that will result in unexpected behaviour.

When `$scope` is being used for scope properties, it can be replaced with `this` and controllerAs syntax.