# Confusion between $scope's in controller and its function?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to UI. I do have confusion between `$scope`'s in AngularJS. Please refer below snippet.

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

mainApp.controller(['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.name = "John";

}]);
```

So, what's the difference between `$scope` and `function($scope)`? Also how can we relate both? Is it required to have `$scope` parameter? Please explain me with an example. I really appreciate that.

Thanks,
John

Comment: it is called Dependency Injection. Refer docs  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 1):

1.When you apply Minification of Following Angular JS code:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
mainApp.controller(['$scope','$log', function($scope,$log) {
$scope.name = "John";
$log.log("John");
}]);
```

Minified Version :

```
var mainApp=angular.module("mainApp",
[]);mainApp.controller(["$scope","$log",function(n,o)
{n.name="John",o.log("John")}]);
```

2.When you apply Minification of Following Angular JS code:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
mainApp.controller(function($scope,$log) {
$scope.name = "John";
$log.log("John");
});
```

Minified Version :

```
var mainApp=angular.module("mainApp",[]);mainApp.controller(function(n,a)
{n.name="John",a.log("John")});
```

3.When you apply Minification of Following Angular JS code:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
mainApp.controller(function($log,$scope) {
$scope.name = "John";
$log.log("John");
});
```

Minified Version :

```
var mainApp=angular.module("mainApp",[]);mainApp.controller(function(n,a)
{n.name="John",a.log("John")});
```

You will Notice in Ex-2 and Ex-3 that you have interchanged the Dependency place of $scope and $log then also your minified version is the same ,this will give you `dependency Injection error` ,so we place a String value as String Value can't be minified as you can see in Ex-1.

It is not required to have $scope each time you define your controller but $scope provides important functionality like `binding the HTML (view) and the JavaScript (controller).` . 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 0):

> what's the difference between `$scope` and `function($scope)`?

When you do

```
  mainApp
  .controller(
    ['$scope', //line 1
      function($scope) //line 2
      {
      }
    ]);
```

- In `line 1` it refers to [`$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope), which is an object that refers to the application model
- In `line 2` it is the variable (conveniently called *$scope* too) in which the (mentioned above) *$scope* object is injected. This variable can have any other name, `$scope` is used as a way to keep a suggestive reference through the whole code.

For instance, your example would work too if I change its name to `myFunnyScope` like this:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

mainApp.controller(['$scope', function(myFunnyScope) {
    myFunnyScope.name = "John";
}]);
```

> Also how can we relate both?

Taking as reference my previously posted snippet, you can tell the *$scope* object is being injected in the `myFunnyScope` variable, it means you use `myFunnyScope` as if it were `$scope` itself.

> Is it required to have `$scope` parameter?

As long as you need to get access to all benefits provided by the mentioned *$scope* object, when you do [minification](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources) it is required to inject the object (`[$scope, ...`) into the holder (`function($scope) { ...`) in order to not get the AngularJS application broken. Otherwise, no, you don't need to inject the object, but then you have to explicitly call it `$scope` in the function parameter so AngularJS knows it has to inject the `$scope` object inside it. This rule applies not only to `$scope`, but to all other AngularJS related services, factories, etc such as `$timeout`, `$window$`, `$location`, etc.

You might want to read about the [AngularJS injection mechanism](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) and consider using the [controller as](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) syntax for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952006/angularjs-scope-vs-this-what-is-the-use-of-scope/40952350#40952350) if you do not want to use `$scope` directly.