# What are $ctrl in angularjs? when to use $ctrl vs $scope on view?

Tags: angularjs

In example `$ctrl` is used on view

```
<b>Heroes</b><br>
<hero-detail ng-repeat="hero in $ctrl.list" 
             hero="hero" 
             on-delete="$ctrl.deleteHero(hero)" 
             on-update="$ctrl.updateHero(hero, prop, value)">
</hero-detail>
```

When to use `$ctrl` and when to use `$scope` for interacting with view?

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: it's *controllerAs* syntax, e.g. `ng-controller="myCltr as $ctrl"`. This allows you to bind data to `this` instead of `$scope`, e.g. `var vm = this; vm.list = [];`

Comment: There is a similar question here about the _controllerAs_ syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40952006/5640649

Answer (score 5):

In views, you can bind an alias to your controller to make it easy to reference `$scope` variables.

This is useful when you nest controllers and you don't want to reference something from a different controller. since `$scope` follows a hierarchical data structure.

So in order to scope your controller you can use this syntax.

For example, having two controllers, both with the same a variable 'name', you can do this:

```
<body ng-controller="ParentCtrl as ptr">
    <input ng-model="name" /> {{ptr.name}}

    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as chl">
        <input ng-model="name" /> {{chl.name}} - {{ptr.name}}
    </div>
</body>
```

this makes it easy to reference the scope variables.

```
<b>Heroes</b><br>
<hero-detail ng-repeat="hero in $ctrl.list" 
             hero="hero" 
             on-delete="$ctrl.deleteHero(hero)" 
             on-update="$ctrl.updateHero(hero, prop, value)">
</hero-detail>
```

After **Angulajs 1.5**, if you are using **components**, the default alias is `$ctrl` and of course you can override it.