# Is using this operator does one way binding while $scope does two way binding?

Tags: angularjs

What are the differences of using `this` and `$scope` in AngularJS, does `this` only do one way data binding, while `$scope` does two way data binding?

Answer (score 3):

Angular does additional processing on `$scope` that it does not do to `this`.

See [Angular: Should I use this or $scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619740/angular-should-i-use-this-or-scope) for more.